# Autocomplete Search Using Google Maps Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete

I'm doing a project where you can browse destinations.  I want to make use of the autocomplete search to help the user search destinations.

My problem is, the fragment shows the search bar I need to use, but when I click on it to search - it opens the overlay search bar in which I can type, but disappears so fast I can't even use it.

**activity_search.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/traintracks_image"
    tools:context="travel_buddyapp.travelbuddyapp.Search_Activity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bBack_Search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        android:textColor="#f7f7f9"
        android:background="@null"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="2dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSearch_Search"
        android:layout_width="232dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Search"
        android:background="#4a90e2"
        android:textColor="#f7f7f9"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edSearch"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/bBack_Search"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="286dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="Enter your dream destination"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#f7f7f9"
        android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/bBack_Search"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="49dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edSearch"
        android:layout_width="335dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="I want to visit..."
        android:textColor="#b6bdc6"
        android:background="#f7f7f9"
        android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/bBack_Search"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        android:layout_width="335dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/searched_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bSearch_Search"
        android:layout_marginLeft="154dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Search_Activity.java**

```
public class Search_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button but1;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    TextView txtPlaceDetailss;
    private static final String TAG = "Search_Activity";

    public void init(){
        but1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.bBack_Search);
        but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                Intent toy = new Intent(Search_Activity.this,WelcomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(toy);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_);
        init();

        txtPlaceDetailss = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.searched_address);

        PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                Log.i("Tag", "Place: " + place.getName());
                String placeDetailsStr = place.getName() + "\n"
                        + place.getId() + "\n"
                        + place.getLatLng().toString() + "\n"
                        + place.getAddress() + "\n"
                        + place.getAttributions();
                txtPlaceDetailss.setText(placeDetailsStr);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                Log.i("Tag", "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can anyone please assist me?

Answer (score 0):

Does Your google_maps_key is valid and did you enable the key?

Comment: I did add it in my manifest file and created it.  How do I knwo if it is enabled and valid though?